# ASP.NET Core MVC exception when using AddSignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC 3.0 API project. I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` v3.0

In the `Startup.cs`, inside the `ConfigureServices` method, when I type the below and run the application, I get an exception:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();
var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();
```

The `AppUser` class is something like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Domain
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The exception I am getting is this:

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]'.)
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]'.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]'.
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
>          at Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\XXXXXXXX\api\Program.cs:line 19
>        ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped 
>       ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]'.
>        ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Domain.AppUser]'.
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, 
>       Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)<---

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you create a new `IdentityBuilder` like that?

Comment: well, i am following an online tutorial. so this is how they did it. I want to be able to inject SignInManager as a service so that i can use it within the project. Would appreciate if you have another way of doing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use `AddDefaultIdentity` which help you register the services like `SignInManager` . You can refer to below steps :

1. Edit project file to install packages :

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

       <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
       </PropertyGroup>

       <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
           <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
           <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
       </PackageReference>
       </ItemGroup>

   </Project>
   ```
2. Create `DataContext` :

   ```
   public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
   {
       public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
           // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
           // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Startup.cs :

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(
           Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

   services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
   ```
4. Inject `SignInManager` :

   ```
   private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
   private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
   private readonly DataContext _context; 

   public WeatherForecastController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager,SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, DataContext dbContext)
   {
       _userManager = userManager;
       _signInManager = signInManager;
       _context = dbContext;

   }
   ```

And use like :

`await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);`

Comment: I am getting an error saying 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDefaultIdentity'. It seems that this code is useful when I am using Razor. I am actually writing an API

Comment: @Yousi , no , make sure you have install the nuget package, it works in api also.

Comment: Try include `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` .

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, inside the `ConfigurationServices` method in `Startup.cs`, add `services.AddAuthentication();` after the following code block:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();
var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();
```

For anyone who is following along with Neil Cummings course *Complete guide to building an app with .Net Core and React*, this is the solution that he provides later on.

Comment: What if I don't want to use a database to store that? If I only use AD for signing in? In `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<...>()` I don't know what to put in the context.